# Newton-Raphson with Zeroth-Order Continuation is not Converging

Tags: python, newton-method, computational-chemistry

I am trying to solve this system of nonlinear equations using Newton-Raphson method with continuation (zeroth-order continuation).

$F_1(x, y, \xi, \nu) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{\nu}\right) \left(1 - x\right) - \left(1 - \frac{1}{\nu}\right) \left(1 - y\right) + \log{\left(x \right)} - \log{\left(y \right)} + \frac{\left(1 - x\right)^{2}}{\xi} - \frac{\left(1 - y\right)^{2}}{\xi}$
$F_2(x, y, \xi, \nu)=\frac{\nu x^{2}}{\xi} - \frac{\nu y^{2}}{\xi} + x \left(1 - \nu\right) - y \left(1 - \nu\right) + \log{\left(1 - x \right)} - \log{\left(1 - y \right)}$

The goal is to find the solution $(x,\xi)$ for each value of $y \in [0.01, 0.99]$ for when $\nu=500$. We know the solution $(x, \xi)$ at $\nu=1$ for any given value of $y$ to be: $x=1-y$ and $\xi=\frac{1-2x}{\ln{\frac{1-x}{x}}}$.

Newton-Raphson with zeroth-order continuation is performed by iterations of the following equation:

$F(\nu', X^{(k)})+J(\nu', X^{(k)})(X^{(k+1)}-X^{(k)}) = 0$

Where $X^{(k)}$ is the solution at the old value of $\nu$, $\nu'$ is the new value, and $X^{(k+1)}$ is the solution at the new value.

The workflow goes like this:

- Iterate over the range of points of possible values of $y$

  - Iterate over the range of points of possible values of $\nu$:

    - starting with $\nu=1$, analytically determine the solution $(x, \xi)$ using the previous equations.
    - Use this solution at $\nu=1$ as the initial guess for Newton-Raphson method
    - Start the Newton-Raphson iterations

You can also swap the loops over $\nu$ and $y$, and find all the values of $(x, \xi)$ for each increment of $\nu$.

I am using SimPy and NumPy. For some reason, the code does not work, after a certain number of iterations over $\nu$ it starts giving `nan` values. I tried inspecting the different values, I found that the Jacobian (and inverted Jacobian) contains very large values, on the order of 1E6 or more, which might be the cause. This also causes the values of $x$ and $\xi$ to go out of the expected range.

The code:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sm
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy.abc import xi, nu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


x, y = sm.symbols("x y")
variables = sm.Matrix([x, xi])

f1 = (
    sm.log(x)
    - sm.log(y)
    + (1 - 1 / nu) * (1 - x)
    - (1 - 1 / nu) * (1 - y)
    + (1 - x) ** 2 / xi
    - (1 - y) ** 2 / xi
)
f2 = (
    sm.log(1 - x)
    - sm.log(1 - y)
    + (1 - nu) * x
    - (1 - nu) * y
    + nu * x**2 / xi
    - nu * y**2 / xi
)

f = sm.Matrix([f1, f2])

J = f.jacobian(variables)
J_inv = J**-1

# Convert the inverted Jacobian and the system of equations to lambda functions, so code runs faster
J_inv = lambdify([x, xi, y, nu], J_inv)
f = lambdify([x, xi, y, nu], f)

y_list = np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 1000)
x_list = (1-y_list)
xi_list = ((1 - 2 * x_list ) / (np.log((1 - x_list ) / x_list )))

TOLERANCE = 1e-6

for index, y_iter in enumerate(y_list):
    x_var = x_list[index]
    xi_var = xi_list[index]

    # Decreasing step size for nu should give better results in theory
    for nu_iter in np.linspace(1.01, 500, 1000):
        for iter in range(100):
            J_inv_eval = J_inv(x_var, xi_var, y_iter, nu_iter).squeeze()
            f_eval = f(x_var, xi_var, y_iter, nu_iter).squeeze()
            delta_x = -np.matmul(J_inv_eval, f_eval)

            if (x_var + delta_x[0]) < 0 or (x_var + delta_x[0]) > 1  or (xi_var + delta_x[1]) < 0 or (xi_var + delta_x[1]) > 2:
                print('Value out of range.')
                break

            x_var += delta_x[0]
            xi_var += delta_x[1]

            error = np.linalg.norm(f(x_var, xi_var, y_iter, nu_iter).squeeze())

            if error < TOLERANCE:
                print(f'Converged at error = {error}')
                break
```

The results should look like:

[image: Two-phase coexistence curves for polymer solutions]

Comment: Before you do any continuation, can you solve the nonlinear system as written with Newton's Method? The Jacobian problems you are noticing don't have anything to do with continuation unless the parameters are making the Jacobian blow up.

Comment: @whpowell96 solving directly for $\nu = 500$ does not work.

Comment: It looks like you aren't using a line search or similar globalization method. It may be that your Jacobian has large values in this regime and it is sending the Newton step outside the radius of convergence. Maybe using one of the built in SciPy nonlinear solvers would help here, as they have built in globalization methods and can take user-supplied Jacobians.

Comment: @whpowell96 I tried using SciPy implementation, with zeroth order continuation (assigning solution values from older value of $nu$ as the initial guess for the next value of $nu$ and solving using `scipy.optimize.newton()`) and it is still not converging to the desired solution.

Comment: It looks like this method doesn't use a line search either. If your Jacobian is becoming ill-conditioned then globalization techniques such as line search and trust regions or more accurate initial guesses are typically the only ways out